# When using travis-ci to build a project, the data of the corresponding test result data cannot be obtained after the test script runs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, travis-ci, codecov

codecov Unable to find report content in the storage archive.

https://travis-ci.com/ninecat-ui/ninecat-ui/jobs/280868707

this url is the project test stage

and my .travis.yml file is

https://github.com/ninecat-ui/ninecat-ui/blob/master/.travis.yml